# Implement two or more instances simultaneously in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have defined following class in Haskell:

```
class SearchList searchEntity where
    searchList :: [ArtifactTree] -> searchEntity -> [Artifact]
```

I have two equal implementations of this class for different entities:

```
instance SearchList Version where
    searchList [] _ = []
    searchList (artifactTree:[]) element = searchElement artifactTree element
    searchList (x:xs) version = (searchElement x version) ++ (searchList xs version)
instance SearchList Artifact where
    searchList [] _ = []
    searchList (artifactTree:[]) element = searchElement artifactTree element
    searchList (x:xs) artifact = (searchElement x artifact) ++ (searchList xs artifact)
```

Is there a way to combine two equal instances into one to avoid code duplication? For example, I am looking for something similar to

```
instance SearchList {Version, Artifact} where
    searchList [] _ = []
    searchList (artifactTree:[]) element = searchElement artifactTree element
    searchList (x:xs) version = (searchElement x version) ++ (searchList xs version)
```

Comment: Can you show what exactly is `Version` and `Artifact` ?

Comment: Maybe, you should generalize `Version` and `Artifact` and make something like type family. Show code for those types.

Comment: Also, what type is `List` exactly?

Comment: If the `searchList` method is identical for both types, why do you even need a class in the first place?

Comment: Both look as a `map` to me.

Comment: Specifically, `searchList xs thing = concatMap (searchElement thing) xs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Reid Henrichs said, there is no way to do this in general, and it's probably not necessary in this case. However, there are a couple things that can be very helpful.

#### Higher-kinded types

Don't get scared off by the crazy name. The `Maybe` type, for example, is "higher-kinded", because you can't have a value of type `Maybe`—it needs to have type `Maybe a` for some `a`. There are two ways to deal with type classes for higher-kinded types. One way is to actually make a higher-kinded class. Another is to make a polymorphic instance. So for example, you can have

```
class Foo f where
  foom :: f a -> Int

instance Foo [] where
  foom lst = length lst
```

or you can have

```
class Bar t where
  boom :: t -> Int

instance Bar [a] where
  boom lst = length lst
```

#### Helper functions

Suppose you have a class, and want the instances for lists of `Int` and lists of `Bool` and lists of `[Bool]` to all act in about the same way, but other sorts of lists to do something else. You can write list functions implementing that common behavior, and then write three tiny little instance declarations that use the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a typeclass for this function. There is no way to do what you are asking in general, but if your functions have identical implementations then they can often be written without a typeclass anwyway.